# How to bypass Google reCAPTCHA for testing using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, recaptcha

I am using Selenium to test my Spring based web application. Can you suggest a solution to bypass google reCAPTCHA while testing the application.

I am running automation test in this environment. So manually checking the "I'm not a robot" of reCAPTCHA is not possible.

For testing purpose I am using test key on my testing environment given on below location.

[Google reCAPTCHA Testing Key](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)

[image]

I am using Angular 5 as front-end of my application. I am using ng-recaptcha library for adding reCAPTCHA in ui.

Comment: The main purpose of reCapcha is to prevent: crows and bots, to access current form/page. If y can hack this defense, send Google your CV.
In your case, just mock this service. It's no need to test this service. It's working :)

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov I am sure atleast **crows** can't answer to question tagged with `Selenium` :)

Comment: haha :) I mean spiders. hahha :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know your exact code but you should be able to run your server with a System Property or some flag which indicate that the reCaptcha should be disable and to not add it to the form in the first place.

Comment: It is possible but require lot of code change. But I am looking for a simple way of fixing this issue.

Comment: You should be careful because what you are doing is effectively creating a security hole which allow to bypass the captcha, that's why it need to be made in such a way it will be very hard to do it accidentally

Comment: This is not a great solution as it introduces an unnecessary difference between the production and test environments. A better approach is to use the test key and find a way to simulate clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by finding the x and y coordinates of the checkbox in reCAPTCHA and click the element.

```
WebElement captcha = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div"));
        builder.moveToElement(captcha, 50, 30).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: What is the `builder` variable?

Comment: Its the org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action object.

Answer (score 7):

You should "switch" the driver to iFrame to locate exactly the checkbox of reCaptcha.
Commands:

```
WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_reCaptcha_iFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);
```

// Now can click on checkbox of reCaptcha now.

```
WebElement iFrame_checkbox = 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_of_reCaptcha_checkbox"));
iFrame_checkbox.click();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. There are perfectly valid reasons to use test keys and want selenium to perform an actual click on the reCaptcha box in certain testing environments.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any feasible way. If you look the below code for almost all reCAPTCHA

[image: reCAPTCHA dom]

- 1st there is iframe : You can switch to it
- 2nd there is shadow-root element "#document", I didn't find any way to override it. I used querySelector, didn't work for me.
- But if you pass the shadow-rootelement "#document", then you can click on the check box or here the 3rd yellow mark.

---

The only way is to resolve this, we have to disable it on lower environment and test it using automation.

> Let me know, if anyone find out a proper way.